# RHEL8: Cannot read / modify / delete directory

Tags: filesystems, directory, ext4, flash-memory

We have a cluster of flash drives (8TB) mounted on /data as per:

```
/dev/mapper/vg.data-lv.data on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

There are a couple of directories inside /data with one being `tmp`:

```
ls -lst /data/
total 1036468
...
1036360 drw-r--r-- 1 secadmin sudo 1061183488 Nov  8 13:10 tmp
...
```

For some reason this folder /data/tmp seems to be malfunctioning: Any attempts to modify its, delete it, list it contents etc. leads to the respective command idling / blocking forever not returning any results:

```
# ls /data/tmp
^C
#
# rm -rf /data/tmp
^C
#
```

I already ran `fsck.ext4 -fvy` to check the underlying file system but everything seems to be fine.

How can I get control back over this directory and what is the underlying issue that I lost control over it?

Comment: You might try getting details on the inode with the `debugfs` command. You can even delete the inode, then run fsck to try to recover any files that were in the directory. However, a directory usually has a link count of at least 2, not 1, and permissions with `rwx`. A 1Gbyte directory is huge. Any operation on it, like `ls` will take a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @meuh wrote, this looks like a very large directory, and may have thousands or millions of files and/or subdirectories in it. The GNU `ls` and `rm` tools are not very useful for dealing with such large directories, because they try to sort or otherwise process the full output.

You could try "`find /data/tmp -print`" to generate a list of filenames, or "`find /data/tmp -ls`" to get a long listing.  This should immediately begin printing files, unless the directory has a very large number of empty blocks. In that case, you could also try "`e2fsck -fD <dev>`" to have it shrink the directory, but that may also take a long time.

It would also be useful to determine what was creating so many files in `/data/tmp` so that these files are either cleaned up when no longer needed, and/or put into a proper directory hierarchy instead of a single large directory.